# Apache POI / CTPlotArea / Num Cache - Do not load last data version on chart

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openxml

I use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) 4.1.2 to load chart data from **XLSx** file, parse it, and transform them to **ChartJS JSON** format with [chartjs4java](https://github.com/GotanDev/chartjs4java). The goal is to display excel data in a web app.

My issue concerns data loading from apache POI (with extension `poi-ooxml-schema`).
If data have been upgraded by a machine (without opening Excel), it does not upgrade chart data with new values.

It seems to be located about [NumCache](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/cloud-service/javadoc/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTNumRef.html#getNumCache()) feature on lib.
But I do not find how to load data without this kind of cache.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a simple xlsx file [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16gOIhgU-QwYeF2BzwIOFDp7wut8eHV8i/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108207790636978291372&rtpof=true&sd=true).
   [image: xlsx screenshot]
2. Opening and upgrading this file **without Excel** with external tool.

> For instance, [here](https://gist.github.com/damiencuvillier/c5e440704f9ec5af1737b7959d412ec1) is an example, with Apache POI lib & Java code.
> 3. Trying to get chart data from Apache POI in a separate code.
> Here is a code fragment where I load & browse into my chart data.

```
public LineDataset getDataset(CTLineSer ctLineSer, CTPlotArea plot,  List<CTUnsignedInt> axIdList) {
    LineDataset dataset = new LineDataset();
    int count = 0;

    dataset = this.setLabelToDataset(dataset, ctLineSer);

    CTNumData ctStrVals = ctLineSer.getVal().getNumRef().getNumCache();
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ctStrVals.getPtCount().getVal())); i++) {
        // My code here to parse data
    }
}
```

4. At the end, I put loaded data in a [chartjs](https://github.com/GotanDev/chartjs4java) format to display data.
5. It still displays the old data.
   The right data is loaded only if I open & close (with saving but without doing anything else) the file with Excel.

#### Tries

I've done following tries, without any successful result

- Tried to force data calculation with [`setForceFormulaRecalculation`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setForceFormulaRecalculation-boolean-) method
  `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`
- I've been looking for an other way to load data with CTPlotArea class in Apache POI doc without any result

Comment: "If data have been upgraded by a machine (without opening Excel), it does not upgrade chart data with new values." Surely it does not. Apache POI is not Excel. Neither it renders sheets nor charts nor tables nor pivot tables ... It only is able to read Excel files and is able changing static file content which Excel then renders while opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI neither renders sheets nor charts nor tables nor pivot tables ... It only is able to read Excel files and is able changing static file content which Excel then renders while opening the file.

So if you are updating sheet data Apache POI will not updating dependent chart data automatically. Only Exel will do so while rendering next time while opening the changed file. Fortunately Apache POI since version 4 also is able updating chart data using the `XDDF` stuff. So after updating the sheet data one could also updationg the chart data using `XDDFChartData.Series.replaceData` and `XDDFChartData.Series.plot`.

Following complete example shows that. It uses your `simple.xlsx`. Both the `System.out.println` parts show that chart data values have changed after `updateChartData`.

Disclaimer: This is a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). It is not meant to be productive code. The method `updateChartData` is limited to data sources where category data and series data are in columns.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

class ExcelUpdateChartData {

 static void updateChartData(XSSFChart chart, XSSFSheet dataSheet, 
  int firstDataRow, int lastDataRow, int categoryColumn, int[] seriesColumns) {

  for (XDDFChartData chartData : chart.getChartSeries()) {
   for (int s = 0; s < chartData.getSeriesCount() ; s++) {
    XDDFChartData.Series series = chartData.getSeries(s);
    if (seriesColumns.length > s) {
     XDDFCategoryDataSource category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(
      dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(firstDataRow, lastDataRow, categoryColumn, categoryColumn));
     int seriesColumn = seriesColumns[s];
     XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(
      dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(firstDataRow, lastDataRow, seriesColumn, seriesColumn));
     series.replaceData(category, values);  
     series.plot();
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "./simple.xlsx";
  int firstDataRow = 1;
  int lastDataRow = 6;
  int categoryColumn = 0;
  int[] seriesColumns = new int[]{1};

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFChart chart = drawing.getCharts().get(0);

System.out.println("Chart values before data update:");
System.out.println(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getVal());

  double newValue = 5;
  //update sheet data
  sheet.getRow(firstDataRow+1).getCell(seriesColumns[0]).setCellValue(newValue); 
  sheet.getRow(lastDataRow).getCell(seriesColumns[0]).setCellValue(newValue); 
  //update chart data
  updateChartData(chart, sheet, firstDataRow, lastDataRow, categoryColumn, seriesColumns);

System.out.println("Chart values after data update:");
System.out.println(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getVal());

  filePath = "./simpleChanged.xlsx";
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }

}
```